# Response body comes with correct array of objects count but objects are empty

Tags: typescript, express, swagger, swagger-ui, typeorm

I just started a Ts.ED project using TypeORM and Swagger to connect to my database. I have a `UserController.ts` file and a `UserService.ts` file. In the service file, I have an async function in which I retrieve all the users in my db

```
async find(): Promise<Users[]> {
  const users = await this.connection.manager.find(Users);
  return users
}
```

Then in my controller file I call that service function, `find`, for its response to show up on swagger ui

```
@Get('/')
@Returns(200, Array).Of(Users)
async findAll(): Promise<Users[]> {
  const users = await this.usersService.find()
  console.log('user',users)
  return users
}
```

The thing is that the console.log call does print everything as it should, but on swagger ui, the response body only shows

```
[
  {},
  {},
  {}...
]
```

although with the correct count of objects, but empty.

Now, if I change the controller function to

```
@Get('/')
//@Returns(200, Array).Of(Users)
async findAll(): Promise<Users> {
  const users = await this.usersService.find()
  console.log('user',users)
  return users[0]
}
```

the object shows up correctly in swagger ui, with all of its properties.

Any idea why with the array, its objects are showing up empty?

Comment: In your second sample you changed multiple things, which of those was critical to get the "desired" result? "the object shows up correctly" --- and what about `console.log`? How exactly `Users` is implemented? What exact type is `users` variable?

Comment: Alright, each user object has the following properties: `id`, firstName`, `lastName`. The `console.log` prints the objects' properties values everytime, when printing `users` (which is an array of objects) and `users[0]` which is only the first user. 
The line `@Returns(200, Array).Of(Users)` is not crucial in any example. The only thing I changed was the variable type the Promise would return, from `Users[]` to `Users`. Now the "desired" is achieved only in the second sample, when returning one single object, it prints its properties keys and values, now in the first sample...

Comment: ...when returning the array, in prints an array of objects, but the objects show up empty (`{}`), though with the correct count of items.
The users variable depends on the `Promise<Users[]>` line, in the first sample it's a `Users[]` type and in the second sample it's a `Users`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. So, I misunderstood part of TypeORM's and Ts.Ed's documentation. In TypeORM's, the database models are called `Entities`. I had a file a `User.entity.ts` and a `User.model.ts` file, mostly identical so that seemed a bit off at the beginning. Now, by looking at @some-user's answer, as replied, I added the `@Property` decorator in the model file. Then I tried putting it the entity file and the objects in the array were no longer empty, they were showing the properties in which I put the `@Property` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly defined the Users model using the decorator `@Property`?
https://tsed.io/docs/converters.html#usage

Comment: At first, my model was 
```export class User {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```
but after your comment I added the `@Property` decorator to each property, still the response body in swagger ui is an array of empty objects.

Answer (score 0):

When using typescript, nestJs or swagger in controllers, you can use this as well;

```
@Post()
@ApiBody({ type: [objectItem] })
async create(@Body() body: objectItem[]) {
```